# how to add a custom_folder to ""./odoo.py --addons=./addons"

Tags: odoo-9

Please let me know how to add a folder(eg:custom_module) to ""./odoo.py --addons=./addons" in odoo9

i am trying to add custom_module to """./odoo.py --addons=./addons". then getting below error

odoo.py: error: option --addons-path: The addons-path './custom_module' does not seem to a be a valid Addons Directory!

Answer (score 5):

## **There is two way to add custom folder to the odoo addons path:**

### **First the easy one**

to edit the configuration file of the odoo server and locate the line starting with addons_path and appending comma followed by the absolute path to the directory you want to add to the addons path,

so if the custom addons directory is `/home/user_name/new-addons` and the path of your odoo instance is `/home/user_name/odoo` the line should be like this

```
addons_path = /home/user_name/odoo/openerp/addons,/home/user_name/odoo/addons,/home/user_name/new-addons
```

### The second

is when calling the odoo.py script and pass the --addons-path command line argument to it like this

```
$ odoo/odoo.py --addons-path="/home/user_name/odoo/openerp/addons, /home/user_name/odoo/addons, /home/user_name/new-addons"
```

- in this case you must not only pass the path to your custom addons
  directory but also the paths of the base addons
  **(odoo/openerp/addons)** and the core addons directory **(odoo/addons)**    and if your put space after the commas between the paths you will need to quote the list of directories.
- here you can use relative paths but it is relative to the place where
  you call the odoo.py file .
- if you use the second way the custom addons directory has to have at
  least one working module in it or any directory with **init**.py and
  **openerp**.py files inside it or it will give you `"does not seem to a be a valid Addons Directory"` error

**see section : Configuring the addons path in the "Odoo Development Cookbook" book**

Answer (score 2):

```
./odoo.py --addons-path=addons,full_path_of_you_new_addons
```

full path of the directory that contain the module not the path of the module it self like addons in odoo it's a directory contain all module directories

so you folder should be like this :

```
   -new_addons  : #full path of this folder
        ->you_module
              ->__openerp__.py
              ->__init__.py
```

NB: parameter for

```
 ./odoo.py  -r user_name -w password  --db_host=host_adress --addons-path=addons,new_addons,"new_addons",..  --update=module_name,module_name,...  --xmlrpc-port=8069
```